# Function with variable number of arguments, passed as template argument

Tags: c++

The idea is to have foo(...) as a function argument, with foo(...) being optionaly called.
I can achieve this, like this:

```
template <typename T, typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
T value_or(const optional<T>& value, const FUNCTION& fp, const ARGS&... args)
{
    if (value)
        return *value;
    else
        return fp(args...);
}
```

For example, I can do:

```
int foo0() { return 10; }
int foo1(int x) { return x; }
int foo2(int x, double ) { return x; }

optional<int> x;
value_or(x, foo0);
value_or(x, foo1, 34);
value_or(x, foo2, 34, 5.0);
```

But I would like the same, using this notation:

```
value_or(x, foo0());
value_or(x, foo1(34));
value_or(x, foo2(34, 5.0));
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: the interest of the function value_or that I have described is that the function foo is **never called if std::optional is valid**.
This means, a potential expensive call is avoided.
With the classical function std::optional::value_or(foo()), foo() would be called always, whatever the state of std::optional.

Comment: `optional` is a `std::optional`, right? Or is it `boost::optional`? Can you please specify?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you try to solve with your `value_or` function? Why do you want to *call* the `foo` functions and pass their result to the `value_or` function? That makes the calling of e.g. `foo0` actually happen when you call `value_or`, it's no longer conditional.

Comment: see my additional note

Comment: So basically, you want lazy evaluation of the second parameter based on the (runtime!) value of `x`? Unfortunately, this is C++, not a functional language ...

Comment: @dhke Yes, you summarize well my attempt.